# Understand nz function in this line of code

Tags: pine-script

I have never used pine script lanuage and need help understanding this part of the code:

`//val = linreg(source  -  avg(avg(highest(high, 20), lowest(low, 20)),sma(close,20)), 20,0) //bcolor = iff( val > 0, iff( val > nz(val[1]), lime, green),`

My question is what does `nz(val[1]` mean?

Would appreciate the help.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

This function takes an argument and if it is equal to na then it returns 0, otherwise it returns the argument’s value.

source: https://usethinkscript.com/threads/nz-in-pinescript-equivalent-in-thinkscript.2953/

Answer (score 3):

In PineScript, the `nz()` function replaces `NaN` (`na`) values with zeros (or given value) in a series.

The syntax for the `nz()` function is:

```js
nz(source, replacement)
nz(source)
```

[Reference](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_nz)

Returns the value of `source` if it is not `na`. If the value of `source` is `na`, the function returns zero, or the `replacement` argument when one is used.